# Add Image to Aga.Control.Tree.Node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Someone has a solution for this?
Or any other hints for a multiselect treeview with images?

```
TreeModel _model = new TreeModel();
treeViewAdv.Model = _model;
treeViewAdv.BeginUpdate();



Node clampingNode = new Node("Hello");
Bitmap bitmap =  (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("release.png");
clampingNode.Image = bitmap;

NodeTextBox ntb = new NodeTextBox();
ntb.DataPropertyName = "Text";
this.treeViewAdv.NodeControls.Add(ntb);
 treeViewAdv.EndUpdate();
```

I was searching for an alternative of the ootb treeview, because I need multiselection.
So there was hints to treeviewadv.
It took quite some time to let it run, because I tried always to add TreeNodeAdv, it was a just a mess. So These Nodes helped, but noe I struggle with adding Images like the ootb version.